# Custom checkbox is not aligned with text

Tags: html, css, gwt, checkbox

Im im trying to create custom checkboxes in GWT using only CSS
So far i was able to style checkboxes that DO NOT have text near them.
However checkboxes with text are looking messy

Current state: 
[image: Messy style]

Desired behaviour:
[image: Right behaviour]

```
  <span class="gwt-CheckBox" id="i294">
<input tabindex="0" id="gwt-uid-3" type="checkbox" value="on">
<label for="gwt-uid-3">Run task immediately after finish</label>
</span>
```

**HTML**

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;

}
input[type="checkbox"]+label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(images/custom_html_elements_sprite.png) 0 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;

    background: url(images/custom_html_elements_sprite.png) -64px 0;
}
```

**CSS**

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT:**

fiddle provided

https://jsfiddle.net/2j0zke2z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solves all problems: (you can set higher padding if you want)

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;

}
input[type="checkbox"]+label {
    display: inline;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  padding:0 0 0 16px;
    background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aspneticons_v1.0_Nov2006/ok_16x16.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    display: inline;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  padding:0 0 0 16px;
    background: url(http://orig03.deviantart.net/9b11/f/2008/101/c/5/war_skull_16x16__by_xicidal.gif);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: All answers were good but this fits best as GWT uses different approaches when generating HTML. Your solutions is working for all approaches

Answer (score 0):

Add `Padding-left:20px` to your label and remove the `width` and `height` form label. Also include `no-repeat` to your background image.

```
input[type="checkbox"]+label {
    display: inline-block;       
    background: url(images/custom_html_elements_sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-left:20px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(images/custom_html_elements_sprite.png) -64px 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2j0zke2z/2/

Comment: It is only making icon larger. I have edited my question and provided fiddle ill be glad if you can have a look

Comment: Removing `height` might make the image size larger.

Comment: add `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for, just change images, cus I took some by default:

```css
span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] +
 label span {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
    background-size: 20px;
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    background: transparent;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span::before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customicondesignoffice2/128/success.png');
    background-size: 20px;
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input tabindex="0" id="gwt-uid-3" type="checkbox" value="on">
<label for="gwt-uid-3"><span></span>Run task immediately after finish</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS :

```
input[type="checkbox"]+label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(images/custom_html_elements_sprite.png) 0 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 16px;

    background: url(images/custom_html_elements_sprite.png) -64px 0;
}
```

Does you really want width of 16px only, If you keep it auto it will solve your problem.

Please check this [fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbp89uw9/) provided here.

Answer (score 0):

Text has been wrapped due to specified `width`.

Just remove the `width` and add `padding-left` as necessary. Also include `no-repeat` to your background image. [**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2j0zke2z/4/)

**Note:** You can resize the background image using [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

---

**Snippet**

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aspneticons_v1.0_Nov2006/ok_16x16.gif) no-repeat;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  /*  background: transparent; */
  background: url(http://orig03.deviantart.net/9b11/f/2008/101/c/5/war_skull_16x16__by_xicidal.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<span class="gwt-CheckBox" id="i294">
<input tabindex="0" id="gwt-uid-3" type="checkbox" value="on">
<label for="gwt-uid-3">Run task immediately after finish</label>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edited :**
is this you want?

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;

}
input[type="checkbox"]+label {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aspneticons_v1.0_Nov2006/ok_16x16.gif) 0 0;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding-left:25px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(http://orig03.deviantart.net/9b11/f/2008/101/c/5/war_skull_16x16__by_xicidal.gif) 0px 0px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
   padding-left:25px;
}
```

```html
<span class="gwt-CheckBox" id="i294">
<input tabindex="0" id="gwt-uid-3" type="checkbox" value="on">
<label for="gwt-uid-3">Run task immediately after finish</label>
</span>
```

Comment: Not at all im trying to create custom checkboxes with text. In your solution default OS checkbox is visible